# How to derive Catalan's general term from its recursive formula if you do not use generating functions or combinatorics

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Like, if I want to derive the general term from $ a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+2a_{n} $, I write it as $ a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}=2(a_{n+1}+a_{n}) $, and then $ \left\{a_{n+1}+a_{n}\right\} $ is a geometric sequence. Is there a way to rewrite the recursive formula of the Catalan number so that a geometric sequence can be found and then we derive the general term of it?

Note: derive $ C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\tbinom{2n}{n} $ from $ C_0=1 $ and $ C_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} C_iC_{n-i}$

Comment: Well, it's not a geometric sequence. I'm not aware of a way to do this by directly manipulating the recurrence. It's a very complicated recurrence if you don't analyze it with the generating function.

Comment: Yeah. Anaylizing it with the generating function is a fairly easy way to solve but I'd like to know how I can derive it by directly manipulating this equation. I saw one occasionally before but I cannot find it now.

Answer (score -1):

For any $a_{n+2}=pa_{n+1}+qa_{n}$

You can write it as $a_{n+2}-\alpha a_{n+1}=\beta(a_{n+1}-\alpha a_{n})$

Since $a_{n+2}-(\alpha +\beta)a_{n+1} +\alpha \beta a_{n}= 0$

You can solve $\alpha$, $\beta$ from $p,q$.

Then you get a Geometry sequence $\{ a_{n+1}-\alpha a_{n} \}$ with common ratio $\beta$.

Take summuation on that sequence with some factor, you can find the general term of $a_n$.

Comment: This is not the OP's question.

Comment: Sorry but actually I actually mean how I can derive Catalan number's general term using methods except generating functions and combinatorics.

Comment: Did I use generating functions or combinatorics? I just ask you to solve $\alpha, \beta$ and use sum of G.P.